# Return value using button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, return

I'm trying to return a value using a button, but i just can't get it to work. What i want is the button to return a value which later on can be used to check is the function was used or not. The code that I'm using is the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("200x100")
def bla():
    return 1
Button(master, command = bla, text = 'OK').pack()

if bla == 1:
    print('1')

mainloop()
```

I've also tried to do this using lambda but i could not figure that one out too.

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907627/3110529 as it addresses the issues you're having.

The main concern is that callbacks are designed to just be a behaviour that happens in response to an event and therefore it doesn't entirely make sense for them to return a value. In your program, when you say

`if bla == 1:
    print('1')`

you're asking if the function pointer (or reference?) is equal to `1` which it obviously will never be.

You might be tempted to use global variables to cover this (i.e. store a 'blah' variable, then have the call back set its value) but this is generally considered bad practice. Instead, as in the link, try converting it to a class which will allow you to use member variables to store the results and responses of callbacks in a more organised manner.

Comment: This is actually better than the answer i wrote. Here, have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you arn't saving the return value of `bla()`.

You can do this using a global variable:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("200x100")

gloBla = 0
def bla():
    global gloBla
    gloBla = 1
Button(master, command = bla, text = 'OK').pack()


mainloop()

if gloBla == 1:
    print('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Tknitter Documentation http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm, you can use `BooleanVar` `StringVar` or `IntVar`. They Function as Global variables. In this vase `Variable` Changes with each click of the button.

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
Variable = BooleanVar()
Variable.set(False)

app = Frame(master, borderwidth=10).grid()

def bla():
    print("1")
    if Variable.get() == 0:Variable.set(True)
    else:Variable.set(False)
    print("current state of Variable: {0} ".format(Variable.get()))

button1= Button(app, text = "Click Me",command=lambda:bla()).grid()

mainloop()
```

The `lambda:` command ensure that the function is not called on startup.