# I have a function that takes an argument from .OptionMenu(command=argument), inside the function I assign dataframe

Tags: python, optionmenu

```
def Select_Sensor(MyCurrentDev):
    global mydf
    mydf = df
    if (MyCurrentDev == "Dev00"):
        mydf = df.loc[:, ["Date", "Time", "Température du toit #1 (Dev00) [°C]", "Humidité du toit #1 (Dev00) [%Hr]"]]
    elif (MyCurrentDev== "Dev01"):
        mydf = df.loc[:, ["Date", "Time", "Température du toit #2 (Dev01) [°C]", "Humidité du toit #2 (Dev01) [%Hr]"]]
    elif (MyCurrentDev == "Dev02"):
       mydf = df.loc[:, ["Date", "Time", "Température du toit #2 (Dev01) [°C]", "Humidité du toit #2 (Dev01) [%Hr]"]]

return mydf



drop=tk.OptionMenu(root,clicked,"Choose DevXX",LoRa_Devices[0],LoRa_Devices[1],LoRa_Devices[2],LoRa_Devices[3],LoRa_Devices[4],LoRa_Devices[5],
                   LoRa_Devices[6],LoRa_Devices[7],LoRa_Devices[8],LoRa_Devices[9],LoRa_Devices[10],LoRa_Devices[11],command= Select Sensor)
```

Comment: However I can't reach mydf outside of the function

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example), Senseless, in **event-driven programming**, [returning from a `callback=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907627/7414759)