# How to correctly refer to function values in a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a tkinter gui, which starts with a multivariate time series and uses a tkinter gui to allow the user to select and plot certain channel readings in a sliding window created using plotly express. I'm just starting to learn about tkinter and am using Python 3.7 with IDLE on a Mac OS 10.15.4.

In my example below, my time series has seven labelled channels with 10000 time recordings each. The channel labels are 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g' and the series is stored in a 1000-by-7 array, X. Because I won't always know ahead of time the number of channels and their labels in future implementations of this script, I used a loop to create the labelled checkboxes here. The problem occurs when I try to create the data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from tkinter import Tk,Button, Label, Checkbutton,BooleanVar
import pandas as pd


window = Tk()
window.title('My Window')
window.geometry('500x500')

np.random.seed(123)
X = np.random.randn(10000,7)
channels=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
num_channels=len(channels)

'''Checkbuttons for channels, appearing in one row. Each initially set true'''
channel_vars=[]
channel_buttons=[]
for i in range(num_channels):
    channel_vars.append(BooleanVar())
    channel_vars[i].set(True)
    channel_buttons.append(Checkbutton(window,text=channels[i],var=channel_vars[i]))
    channel_buttons[i].grid(row=0,column=i)

'''Determine selected indices'''
def _selected_indices():
    indices=[i for i in range(num_channels) if channel_vars[i].get()]
    print(indices)
selected_indices_btn = Button(window, text="Select",command=_selected_indices)
selected_indices_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

''' Create data frame using only the selected channels'''
df=pd.DataFrame(X[:,indices],columns=channels[indices])
df['x']=df.index

'''Plot selected channels'''
def _plot_selected():
    df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars="x", value_vars=df.columns[:-1])
    fig=px.line(df_melt, x="x", y="value",color="variable",labels = {'x':'time 
    (sec)','variable':'channel'})
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True),type="linear"))
    fig.show()
plot_button = Button(master=window, text="Plot", command=_plot_selected)
plot_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

'''Quit button'''
def _quit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()
quit_button = Button(master=window, text="Quit", command=_quit)
quit_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

The error message tells me that "indices" is unknown when I try to construct my data frame, df, a result that shows I'm missing something basic in terms of callbacks and/or organizing my gui window.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 1):

Not to do with tkinter, it's just that you are assigning the indices values inside the _selected_indices function.

```
'''Determine selected indices'''
def _selected_indices():
    indices=[i for i in range(num_channels) if channel_vars[i].get()]
    print(indices)
```

You are then trying to use your indices outside the scope of the function.

```
''' Create data frame using only the selected channels'''
df=pd.DataFrame(X[:,indices],columns=channels[indices])
```

The bigger problem here is that returning a value from a function to use somewhere else in the program from a tkinter callback isnt ideal.

There is a question here with answers that will help better than I could: [Python - returning from a Tkinter callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903596/python-returning-from-a-tkinter-callback)

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Very helpful. I knew this had something to do with scope. Thanks.